# How to replace symbol 'phi' in R?

Tags: r, symbols

I am using

```
record$Name <- gsub(pattern="phi",replacement="",x=record$Name)
```

The above then replaces even 'phi' in 'Graphics', What is the way to do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `gsub(pattern="^phi$",replacement="",x=record$Name)`

Example, consider the following vector of strings:

```
> string <- c("phi", "graphics", "Graphics")
> gsub("^phi$", "", string)
[1] ""         "graphics" "Graphics"
```

Comment: Maybe `gsub("\\bphi\\b","",string,perl = TRUE)` in case of something like `"graphics phi graphics"`.